# Why does ggplot ignores guides commands in R?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

In the following example `ggplot` draws a legend despite command `guides(fill=FALSE)`. Moreover, it ignores `guides` entirely. E.g., you can't arrange the legend in columns.

Why does it happen and how to get the control over the legend in this case?

```
dfg = data.frame(category=sample(c("A", "B"), 10, replace=T),
                     name=sample(c("x", "y"), 10, replace=T),
                     clients=rnorm(10),
                     rating=rnorm(10))
ggplot(dfg, aes(x = clients, y = rating, color=category, label=name)) +
  geom_text(hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

Comment: There is no `fill` guide in your plot. Do you want `guides(colour=FALSE)`?

Comment: Or `geom_text(hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5 , show_guide=FALSE)`

Comment: @Roland Yes, actually I wanted `guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2, bycol=T))`, and your answer showed how to do it. I'll gladly accept your answer if you post it in answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `fill` guide in your plot. It seems like you want `guides(colour=FALSE)`.

The type of the guides corresponds to what you specify in `aes` and you don't map a `fill` colour there.